# C# - Calling method from an Assembly to other result in DllNotFoundException

Tags: c#, pinvoke, dllimport

I have 3 assemblies, `Assembly2` reference `Assembly1`, and `Assembly3` reference `Assembly2`. But calling a method of `Assembly2` that is declared in `Assembly1` from `Assembly3` results in `DllNotFoundException`.

**Assembly2 -> Assembly1**

**Assembly3 -> Assembly2**

```
    extern "C" namespace Assembly1
    {
       __declspec(dllexport) void SomeMethod(){  }
    }
```

_

```
    namespace Assembly2
    {
       public static class OtherClass
       {
            [DllImport("Assembly1.dll")]
            public static extern void SomeMethod();
       }
    }
```

_

```
    namespace Assembly3
    {
       public static class SomeClass
       {
            public static void SomeOtherMethod()
            {
                OtherClass.SomeMethod(); //DllNotFoundException, Cannot load Assembly1
            } 
       }
    }
```

How can I solve that?

- Add a reference from `Assembly3` to `Assembly1` is the only solution?
- Can this be solve merging `Assembly1` and `Assembly2`? (I don't have idea it this could break something)

Comment: Put the unmanaged DLL in the same directory as the executable

Comment: That works, but I need to copy the unmanaged DLL to the directory of each assembly or each time I move the assemblies. Can this be solve merging the unmanaged DLL with the others? I don't know if `DLLImport` work in that scenario.

Comment: No such thing as merging a managed assembly and an unmanaged DLL. Put the unmanaged DLL in the same directory as the executable.

Comment: It is a basic file-not-found error.  You will always get it when you don't do anything special, the C++ build system has different defaults than the C# build system.  Your C++ project puts the file into the Debug subdirectory of the *solution* directory, the C# project puts the file into the bin\Debug subdirectory of the *project* directory.  Something has to give, beyond copying the file where it can be found, usually the easiest solution is to change the C# project's Project > Properties > Build tab, "Output path" setting from bin\Debug to ..\Debug.  Use Explorer to verify it turned out well

Answer (score 1):

Your options include:

- Unifying all project's output directories; C#: Properties > Build > Output Path, C++: Properties > General > Output Directory.
- Add reference from Assembly3 to Assembly1 (because this takes care of copying the unmanaged assembly to the same output directory)
- `Assembly1.dll` needs to be [somewhere it can be found](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order) (assuming "Assembly1.dll" is just an example of a standard dll)

The first option is likely the best for you.

You would also likely no longer need the reference from Assembly2 to Assembly1.  That reference isn't what makes [PInvoke](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/how-to-call-native-dlls-from-managed-code-using-pinvoke?view=vs-2017)/`DllImport` work- it's not like linking a static library in C++.  PInvoke is handled at runtime instead of compile-time.  That's why you get `DllNotFoundException` at runtime instead of "undefined symbol" like you would when compiling/linking C++.  The reference is copying the unmanaged dll to the output folder where it can be found.